# focus a submit button from ajax response

Tags: javascript, jquery

i get a form-content from a ajax response. Now i want to set the focus to the submit button, to submit the form quickly with push the enter button.

I try it in this way - this is my content from the ajax response

```
<form>...<input type="submit" id="finalsubmit" class="btn btn-success btn-block" value="let's go"></form>

<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $("#finalsaubmit").focus();                                    
});"
</script>;
```

another try with this failed too

```
$("#finalsubmit").load(function() {
  e.preventDefault();
  $("#finalsaubmit").focus();
});
```

What I'm doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

omg, i think it was to early in the morning, the name of id was wrong, not "finalsaubmit" it should be "finalsubmit" too and it works...sorry

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $("#finalsubmit").focus();                                    
});"
</script>;
```

Comment: Glad you solve it. That's why its a good practice to name id's name with - (#final-submit) or pascal case finalSubmit. Cheers.